# ngSrc requires a static string

Tags: angular

In Angular 17, I use

```html
<img [ngSrc]="profilePicture" fill="" priority="" alt="Profile Picture">
```

In browser (Google Chrome), I get this warning:

> NG02964: The NgOptimizedImage directive (activated on
> an  element with the
> `ngSrc="http://localhost:4200/assets/uploads/me.jpg"`) has detected
> that this image is the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) element and has
> had its "ngSrc" attribute modified. This can cause slower loading
> performance. It is recommended not to modify the "ngSrc" property on
> any image which could be the LCP element.

What does it mean not to "modify" the "ngSrc" property? `profilePicture` is not a static string, so it has to be modified.

This is how it is defined:

```js
profilePicture: string = '/';
```

Based on the business logic, this property gets changed by different methods in the same component.

If I use `[src]` instead of `[ngSrc]`, I get the warning "*Use ngSrc (NgOptimizedImage directive) to improve performance*"

So how can I avoid this warning(s)?

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
profilePicture: string = '/';
```

This is not an image. Use the following instead:

```js
profilePicture?: string;
```

As long as `profilePicture` is *null*, `[ngSrc]` will not accept it and you will probably get an error. To avoid this error, use the `img` tag only, when `profilePicture` is set.

Like this:

```html
<img *ngIf="profilePicture" [ngSrc]="profilePicture" fill="" priority="" alt="Profile Picture">
```